# If custom UIView has >1 sublayers, app crashes on touchesBegan, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, automatic-ref-counting

I have a few custom `UIView` objects that all handle drawing like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // ^ I init the layers 1 and 2
    [self.layer insertSublayer:layer1 atIndex:0]; // 1 or more
    [self.layer insertSublayer:layer2 atIndex:1];
}
```

They also have a `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` with nothing else inside but a `NSLog`.

I add them all inside my main `ViewController` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomView *myViewWith1Layer = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 440, 260)];
    [self.view addSubview:myViewWith1Layer];

    CustomViewLayered *myViewWith2Layer = [[CustomViewLayered alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 260, 200, -120)];
    [self.view addSubview:myViewWith2Layers];
}
```

When I run my app, if I tap on a view that has only a single layer - I get my `NSLog` to show, and everything's fine. If, on the other hand, I tap on views with 1+ layers, the app crashes (`objc_msgSend` log shows up with `"EXC_BAD_ACCES (code=1, address=...")`. I guess this is somehow related with **ARC**, which I have enabled.

How do I add multiple layers to a view, without it being messed up by **ARC**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the solution was **definitely** related to ARC.

When initialising my delegates, I immediately assigned them to the `layer.delegate` property, and ARC would remove the object from existence immediately after that.

So for each layer, I add a *strong* `@property (strong, nonatomic) delegatesClass *delegatesName` and initialise straight to the property. After that, I assign the `layer.delegate = self.delegatesName`.

This did solve the issue, although I'm not sure if it is the right way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is an ARC problem, but creating and inserting the layers in `drawRect`
is wrong. This should be done (only once) in the init method of the view, e.g. in `initWithFrame`.

Comment: I'll try to put layers inside `initWithFrame` and come back with a comment :)

Comment: I moved my layers into the init method, but now I get the same `"EXC_BAD_ACCES (code=1, address=...")` there, but this time without taping, just on application load. I'll have to investigate that...